# Whether or not to code to an interface when only certain implementations provide correct behavior

Tags: java

So, I know that coding to an interface (using an interface as a variable's declared type instead of its concrete type) is a good practice in OO code, for a bunch of reasons. This is seen a lot, for example, with Java collections. Well, is referring to an interface in your program still a good thing to do when only certain implementations of that interface provide correct behavior?

For example, I have a Java program. In that program, I have multiple sets of objects. I chose to use a Set, because I didn't want duplicate elements. However, I wanted a list's ordering property (i.e. maintain insertion order). Therefore, I am using a LinkedHashSet as the concrete Set type. One thing these sets are used for is computing a dot product involving the primitive fields of the objects contained in the sets, such as in (simplifying a bit):

```
double dot(LinkedHashSet<E> set, double[] array) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i = 0;
    for(E element : set) {
        sum += (element.getValue()*array[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This method's result is dependent on the set's iteration order, and so certain Set implementations, mainly HashSet, will give incorrect/unexpected results. Currently, I am using LinkedHashSet throughout my program as the declared type, instead of Set, to ensure correct behavior. However, that feels bad stylistically. What's the right thing to do here? Is it okay to use the concrete type in this case? Or maybe should I use Set as the type, but then state in the documentation which implementations will/won't produce correct behavior? I'm looking more for general input than anything specific to the scenario above. In particular, this should apply to really any scenario where you're using the ordering properties of a LinkedHashSet or TreeSet. How do you prevent unintended implementations from being used? Do you force it in the code (by ditching the interface), or do you specify it in the documentation? Or perhaps some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that you should code to interfaces, but only if the assurances they make fit your needs. In your case, if you would only use Set then you are saying: I don't want duplicates, but I don't care about the order. You could also use a List and mean: I care about insertion order, but not about duplicates. There even is a SortedSet but it does not have the ordering you want. So in your case you can't replace LinkedHashSet by one of its interfaces without violating the Liskov substitution principle.

So I would argue that in your case you should stick to the implementation until you really need the to switch to another implementation. With modern IDEs refactoring is not that hard anymore so I would refrain from doing any premature optimizations -- YAGNI and KISS.

Answer (score 1):

Very very great question. One solution is: Make another interface! Say one that extends SortedMap but has a getInsertionOrderIterator() method or an interface that extends Map & has getOrderIterator() & getInsertionOrderIterator() methods.

You can write a quick [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) class that contains a LinkedHashMap & TreeMap as the backend data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can make arguments for either way. As long as you and others maintaining this code know that particular implementations of `Set` might break the rest of the app or library, then coding to the interface is fine. However, if that is not true, then you should use the specific implementation.

The purpose of coding to an interface is to give you flexibility that will not break your app. Take JDBC for instance. If you use the wrong driver it will break your program similar to how you are describing here. However, if let's say Oracle decided to put behavior in their JDBC driver that subtly broke code written to the JDBC spec instead of the specific Oracle driver code then you'd have to choose.

There is no cut and dry, "this is always right" type of answer.

Comment: I kind of disagree. He is requiring something the general contract of the interface does not provide (ordering). If his code breaks depending on implementation he shouldn't be using the general interface.